# how to get id using promise from service using controller

Tags: angularjs, service, controller, couchdb, pouchdb

***hey guys, i have problem with get id. now i cant get '_id' from service. 
this is my service***

```
        application.service('Arrears', [
        function() 
        {
            var db = new PouchDB('localhost:5984/arrears');

            return {         
                get: function (_id) {
                    return db.get(_id)
                    .then(function (object) {
                        return db.remove(object)
                    .catch(function (err) {
                    console.log('error: ' + err); // isn't executed
                });
                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                    console.log('error: ' + err); // isn't executed
                    });
                 },
            }
        }
    ]);
```

***for insert data is ok.
now, this is my controller.***

```
application.controller('ArrearsManagementAllController', ['$location', '$mdSidenav', '$scope', 'Arrears',
        function($location, $mdSidenav, $scope, Arrears)
        {
            $scope.id = Arrears.get();
        }
    ]);
```

***and the last is my template.***

```
<md-list-item
                md-virtual-repeat="i in items"
                ng-click="read(id)">
```

***when i click read, my link show like this***

localhost:8080/arrears_management/all/read/undefined

***my code can't read the id.
please solve my problems. because im new using angularjs and pouchdb.***

***now the console show error like this :-***

```
GET localhost/arrears/_id?_nonce=1447904157421 404 (Object Not Found)
```

Comment: you should use only the code specific to your problem, this is TLDR. Edit the question to avoid downvotes. Template is irrelevant as is most of the code in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrong things with your code:

**1.**

```
get: function (_id) {
                var id = get('_id')
            },
```

does not return anything, and

**2.** `get` is calling a *get* method which is not defined

**3.** you don't have `_id` anywhere to return it. Maybe you want to put it in a service variable after you get it from the database?

**OR**, you probably wanted to do this:

```
get: function (_id) {
       var id = db.get('_id');
       return id;
    },
```

note the ***db***.get instead of just `get` and the very useful **return**. This may depend on the database engine, though...

**EDIT**

even in the controller you have a big issue: `$scope.id = Arrears.get` does a more complicated thing that you wish. You just need to replace it with:

```
$scope.id = Arrears.get();
```

in order to get the value of *id* because you were not calling the `get` method...

Comment: its still can't get the id. this is my link when i click the read. http://127.0.0.1:8080/arrears_management/all/read/undefined see my link show undefined for the get id.

Comment: now the error message like this ***GET http://localhost:5984/arrears/_id?_nonce=1447893369877 404 (Object Not Found)***